# How can I get the current SparkSession in any place of the codes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created a session in the `main()` function, like this:

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()
```

Now if I want to configure the application or access the properties, I can use the local variable `sparkSession` in the same function.

What if I want to access this `sparkSession` elsewhere in the same project, like `project/module/.../.../xxx.scala`. What should I do?

Comment: Where are you creating sparkSession? What have you tried upto now for accessing it from xxx.scala??

Comment: can you share bit more info on what is ur use case for sharing sparkSession ?

Comment: @hadooper in the main function of the main object. I dont know if i use `getOrCreate()` will get me the same session or not

Comment: @BDR I want to use `setLocalProperty` in some other places. As I defined the session in the main function, idk how to get it outside of the function

Comment: @PC9527 do you expect setLocalProperty will  affect once the session is created ?

Comment: @BDR No, mb somewhere else some in the same project. There is an anwser which pass the session as a parameter to a class, but I think it is not the best solution because the session is not a part of the class.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Once a session was created (anywhere), you can safely use:

```
SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

To get the (same) session anywhere in the code, *as long as the session is still alive*. Spark maintains a single active session so unless it was stopped or crashed, you'll get the same one.

Edit: builder is not callable, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: `builder` is not callable. use `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()`

Answer (score 6):

Since **2.2.0** you can access the **active SparkSession** through:

```
/**
 * Returns the active SparkSession for the current thread, returned by the builder.
 *
 * @since 2.2.0
 */
def getActiveSession: Option[SparkSession] = Option(activeThreadSession.get)
```

or **default SparkSession**:

```
/**
 * Returns the default SparkSession that is returned by the builder.
 *
 * @since 2.2.0
 */
def getDefaultSparkSession: Option[SparkSession] = Option(defaultSession.get)
```

Comment: Are `activeThreadSession` and `defaultSession` private members of SparkSession? When I tried to use them in my notebook, I got `error: value defaultSession in object SparkSession cannot be accessed in object org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession`.

Answer (score 4):

When `SparkSession` variable has been defined as

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()
```

This variable is going to `point/refer` to only one `SparkSession` as its a `val`. And you can always pass to different classes for them to access as well as

```
val newClassCall = new NewClass(sparkSession)
```

Now you can use the same `sparkSession` in that new class as well.

Comment: In this case, if i have passed it to other classes, why i still need a new class (while they are the same sparkSession)? Likes `def f1(ss: SparkSession) = //use ss to do sth.

Comment: I am passing sparksession as an argument to the new class.

Comment: You mean when u instantiate a class?

Comment: But in this way session is like a member of the class, which idk if is proper.

Answer (score 1):

This is a old question and there are couple of answer that are good enough but I would like to give one more approach that can be used to make it work.

You can create a trait that extends from serializable and create spark session as a lazy variable and then through out your project in all the objects that you create, you can extend that trait and it will give you sparksession instance.

Code as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
trait SparkSessionWrapper extends Serializable {
  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    SparkSession.builder().appName("TestApp").getOrCreate()
  }
//object with the main method and it extends SparkSessionWrapper 
object App extends SparkSessionWrapper {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val readdf = ReadFileProcessor.ReadFile("testpath")
   readdf.createOrReplaceTempView("TestTable")
   val viewdf = spark.sql("Select * from TestTable")
 }
}

object ReadFileProcessor extends SparkSessionWrapper{
 def ReadFile(path: String) : DataFrame = {
  val df = spark.read.format("csv").load(path)
  df
 }
}
```

As you are extending the SparkSessionWrapper on both the Objects that you created, spark session would get initialized when first time spark variable is encountered in the code and then you refer it on any object that extends that trait without passing that as a parameter to the method. It works or give you a experience that is similar to notebook.

**Update** : If you even want it to be more generic and have an need to even set the custom appname based on the type of workflow you are running you can do it as below :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
trait SparkSessionWrapper extends Serializable {
  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    createSparkSession(appname)
  }
def appname : String
def createSparkSession(appname : String) : SparkSession ={
    SparkSession.builder().appName(appname).master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  }
//object with the main method and it extends SparkSessionWrapper 
object App extends SparkSessionWrapper {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val readdf = ReadFileProcessor.ReadFile("testpath")
   readdf.createOrReplaceTempView("TestTable")
   val viewdf = spark.sql("Select * from TestTable")
 }
override def appname: String = "ReadFile"
}

object ReadFileProcessor extends SparkSessionWrapper{
 def ReadFile(path: String) : DataFrame = {
  val df = spark.read.format("csv").load(path)
  df
 }
override def appname: String = "ReadcsvFile"
}
```

the only main difference is that you need to create an abstract function inside the trait and then you would have to override that into any of the startup class that you are using to provide the value.